# Does this vector product, based on indexing with a powerset, have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, products

Given two vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ indexed by $2^X$ for some finite set $X$, define $\vec{u} \star \vec{v}$ as the vector of similar type whose dimension indexed by $S \subseteq X$ is:
$$\sum_{\begin{array}{c}S = A \cup B\\[-2em]A\cap B = \emptyset\end{array}} u_A v_B\enspace.$$
**Question:** Does this operation have a name?  Am I seeing that from the wrong point of view?

As a concrete example, if $X = {1, 2}$, $\vec{u} = (x, x_1, x_2, x_{12})$ and $\vec{v} = (y, y_1, y_2, y_{12})$, where the components are, in order, indexed by $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1, 2\}$, then:
$$\vec{u} \star \vec{v} = (xy,\quad x_1y + xy_1, \quad x_2y + xy_2, \quad x_{12}y + x_1y_2 + x_2y_1 + xy_{12})\enspace.$$

Comment: Below the summation, by $A \sqcup B$, do you mean that $A$ and $B$ have to be disjoint?

Comment: @EricAuld: Yes, precisely.  $A$, $B$ form a partition of $S$.

Comment: In what context did this arise Just something you were thinking about?

Comment: @EricAuld: I'm mostly interested in that last term, the one corresponding to the whole set $X$.  In a way, it describes all the possible ways to mark the letters of the word $xy$ by the values $1$ and $2$—that's basically where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a version of the [exterior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra), but missing some signs. It can be described as the multiplication in a certain [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), namely the ring

$$\mathbb{R}[x_1, x_2, \dots x_n]/(x_1^2 = x_2^2 = \dots = 0)$$

where the set $X$ has $n$ elements, and for convenience we'll identify it with the set $\{ 1, 2, \dots n \}$. A "vector indexed by $2^X$," which I'll interpret as a function $f : 2^X \to \mathbb{R}$, is sent to the element

$$\sum_S f(S) \prod_{i \in S} x_i$$

in this ring. The point of the relations $x_i^2 = 0$ is that the product of two monomials $x_S = \prod_{i \in S} x_i$ and $x_T = \prod_{i \in T} x_i$ vanishes as soon as $S$ and $T$ have nontrivial intersection, and if their intersection is trivial then the result is $x_{S \cup T}$.

Comment: I like this!  I was indeed working on $\mathbb{R}[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$, but did not think about quotienting it by the relation $x_1^2=x_2^2 = \cdots = 0$.  Thanks!  (I see no link with the exterior product, though, as I can't understand a line of that wikipedia page ☹)

Comment: @Michaël: the exterior algebra can be described using very similar generators and relations, except that instead of commuting, the generators $x_i$ anticommute: $x_i x_j = - x_j x_i$.